# References to Mechanics (Classical, Quantum, Statistical) using Time-Scale calculus?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations

[Time-Scale Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-scale_calculus), is a theory which unifies ordinary (plus fractional and q-) calculus with discrete (and finite differences) calculus.

In a sense, in a similar way the *Lebesgue integral* (or *Riemann–Stieltjes integral*) unifies both continous integration and discrete summation.

The rationale is to use **time-scales** (or measure chains) which include continous (*dense*) points and discrete or semi-discrete (*scattered*, *isolated*) points.

Even [**Variational Calculus**](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.3597) (and **Euler-Lagrange equations**) and [**Noether's Theorem**](http://arxiv.org/abs/0709.0400) have been (recently) generalised (more or less) to *time-scale calculus*.

Any references to (unified) formulation of Mechanics (Classical, Quantum, Statistical) in time-scale calculus (and their relevance)?

UPDATE:

A initial survey paper (2002) on ["R. Agarwal, M. Bohner, D. O’Regan and A. Peterson, Dynamic equations on time scales: a
survey, J. Comput. Appl. Math. 141 (2002), no. 1-2, 1–26."](http://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fpublication%2F222577731_Dynamic_equations_on_time_scales_a_survey%2Flinks%2F02e7e527e46742aaa7000000&ei=CZ5cVN_wEIeR7AauiYH4Cw&usg=AFQjCNE4JCFnQ-OlYaOhisaO5-pNwc4VtA&bvm=bv.79184187,d.ZGU)

Comment: Premise: I don't know this calculus very well. However I don't see how it may unify the formulation of e.g. classical and quantum mechanics. The dynamics is in both cases a differential equation (not a difference one). There are other mathematical aspects, in my opinion, that emphasize the relevant differences between the two theories (e.g. commutativity vs non-commutativity, non-linear vs linear dynamics).

Comment: @yuggib, one can say the main difference between clasical/quantum is the finite value of the planck constant $h$ (e.g Ehrenfest theorem). Furthermore there are indeed formal mechanics which are the same for both Classical/Quantum (and Statistical) (this is another question). In any case, "unified" is added extra, even mechanics (classical) references and their relevance is good